# I need to use javascript to turn a "flat" json object into a nested json tree with a 1 to many match ability

Tags: javascript, json

I need use javascript to turn a flat JSON object into a nested tree. The catch that I haven't yet seen in other solutions is that I need to have the ability to match 1 to many... Meaning that I sometimes have a child node that needs to fit into multiple parent nodes.

#### Here is my flat json object:

```
[{
    id: 200,
    title: "child with 2 parents",
    parent_ids: [1, 2]
}, {
    id: 202,
    title: "child with 1 parent",
    parent_ids: [1]
}, {
    id: 1,
    title: "parent 1",
    children: []
}, {
    id: 2,
    title: "parent 2",
    children: []
}]
```

I know that I can might be able to do something like loop through all the parents and children individually to match them up but that seems really inefficient and I'm wondering if there is a better way to go about this?

#### This is the ideal outcome

notice the child with 2 parents gets slotted into both parents

```
[
   {
    id: 1,
    title: "parent 1",
    children: [{
        id: 200,
        title: "child with 2 parents",
        parent_ids: [1, 2]
    }, {
        id: 202,
        title: "child with 1 parent",
        parent_ids: [1]
    }]
   },
   {
    id: 2,
    title: "parent 2",
    children: [{
        id: 200,
        title: "child with 2 parents",
        parent_ids: [1, 2]
    }]
   }
]
```

Comment: Can a child have children? Also, you will probably get the common "what have you tried?" comment as well. There isn't much faster than just straight for loops, though I would probably loop twice. The first would create a map of id to object, and the second would build your structure. You want to avoid nested loops if you have a lot of items - trying to avoid O(n^2) +... though if children can have children, this might be unavoidable.

Comment: Is it always two-level graph? Or can children have their own children and parents their own parents?

Comment: Do you know how to implement a brute force approach with two nested loops, where the outer loop iterates through your array looking for parents and the inner one goes through the array again looking for children of the found parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could collect all nodes in a hash table and get all nodes without parents as result set.

```js
function getTree(data) {
    var temp = {},
        parents = [];

    data.forEach(o => {
        o.children = temp[o.id] && temp[o.id].children;
        temp[o.id] = o;
        if (!o.parent_ids) {
            parents.push(o.id);
            return;
        }
        o.parent_ids.forEach(id => {
            temp[id] = temp[id] || {};
            temp[id].children = temp[id].children || [];
            temp[id].children.push(o);
        });
    });
    return parents.map(id => temp[id]);
}

var data = [{ id: 200, title: "child with 2 parents", parent_ids: [1, 2] }, { id: 202, title: "child with 1 parent", parent_ids: [1] }, { id: 1, title: "parent 1", children: [] }, { id: 2, title: "parent 2", children: [] }],
    tree = getTree(data);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```